# Observing a property of a child view

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to work out the best method of observing a property on another view instance within Ember. Currently I have the following code that does not seem to be working correctly. Looking at documentation I can't seem to find anything on whether or not observers will only work for self.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  myProperty: false,
  observerFiredCount: 0,

  testObserver: function() {
    var count = this.get('observerFiredCount');
    this.set('observerFiredCount', count + 1);
  }.observes('myProperty'),

  buttonClick: function(event) {
    if(this.get('myProperty')) {
      this.set('myProperty', false);
    } else {
      this.set('myProperty', true);
    }
  },

  willInsertElement: function() {
    var button = this.$('a');
    button.click($.proxy(this.buttonClick, this));
  }
});

App.TestObserverView = Ember.View.extend({
  testObserverAcrossViews: function() {
    console.log('hello world');
  }.observes('App.ApplicationView.myProperty')
});
```

I guess theres 2 questions that would be helpful here.

**1. Is it possible to observe a property on another object instance.**

**2. What path do I use to access a childview instance?**

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I feel as though there could be a cleaner way to do this :)

Comment: Ok so firstly `App.ApplicationView` isn't an instance, it's a subclass, so the path `App.ApplicationView.myProperty` isn't actually a valid path.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to all your questions is that you're approaching the problem from the wrong perspective. Views are destroyed. They are short lived. They don't exist globally. You need a controller. Controller's are long lived and meant to be bound to. Instead of trying to observe a view, you should observe a controller.

So, when the click event happens on the view, set a property on the controller. Other parts of the application can bind to that property on the controller.

Comment: your input just helped me--but can you suggest some reading of controllers for people new to the controller concept? I love MVVM, but do see that I need to start incorporating a controller as well. I'll only be needing this for navigation properties of controls (I like the simplicity of interaction triggers and keeping the interaction between views in the xaml). Thanks for revisiting :)